# >How to solve $F(t) = a\sin{t} - 2 \int^t_0 F(u) \cos(t - u) du$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> How to solve $F(t) = a\sin{t} - 2 \int^t_0 F(u) \cos(t - u) du$

The answer is $F(t) = at e^{-t}$

I thought to integrate it and then differentiate it, but the function $ F(u) $ is not defined , also the function is dependent on two variables. Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Use the Laplace Transform.

Comment: Is there any way other than laplace transform to solve it @Cesareo

Comment: Could you check again your task, is the upper integral boundary really constant?

Comment: Try differentiating F twice to get a DE.

Comment: thanks for correcting me @LutzL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Originally** the equation was written as $F(t)=a\sin(t)-2\int_0^1F(u)\cos(t-u)du$.
Computing the second derivative you get 
$$
F''(t)=-a\sin(t)+2\int_0^1F(u)\cos(t-u)du=-F(x)
$$
so that $$F(t)=R\cos(t-\phi).$$ Now insert into the original equation
$$
R\cos(t-\phi)=a\sin(t)+2\int_0^1R\cos(u-\phi)\cos(t-u)du\\
=a\sin(t)+\int_0^1R\cos(t-\phi)du + \int_0^1R\cos(2u-t-\phi)du\\
=a\sin(t)+R\cos(t-\phi)-\frac R2[\sin(2-t-\phi)-\sin(0-t-\phi)]
\\~\\
\implies 0=a\sin(t)-R\sin(1)\cos(1+t+\phi)
$$
Now compare coefficients, $a=R\sin(1)$, $1+\phi=\frac\pi2$.

---

In the **corrected task** $F(t)=a\sin(t)-2\int_0^tF(u)\cos(t-u)du$ with upper boundary $t$ instead of $1$, compute the first and second derivative
\begin{align}
F'(t)&=a\cos(t)-2F(t)\cos(0)+2\int_0^tF(u)\sin(t-u)du\\
F''(t)&=-a\sin(t)-2F'(t)+2F(t)\sin(0)+2\int_0^tF(u)\cos(t-u)du\\
&=-F(t)-2F'(t)
\end{align}
The differential equation $F''+2F'+F=0$ has indeed solutions $F(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2te^{-t}$, checking the initial conditions $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)=a$ should give the provided solution

Answer (score 2):

In the initial equation

$$F(t) = a\sin{t} - 2 \int^t_0 F(u) \cos(t - u) du$$

we recognize the convolution of causal functions (see Remark below) :

$$F(t) = a\sin{t} - 2 (F \star \cos)(t)$$

inviting to use Laplace Transform :

$$\hat{F}(s) = a\dfrac{1}{1+s^2}- 2 \hat{F}(s) . \dfrac{s}{1+s^2}$$

whence :

$$\hat{F}(s) \dfrac{1+2s+s^2}{1+s^2}= a\dfrac{1}{1+s^2}$$

Multiplying by $1+s^2$ gives :

$$\hat{F}(s)=a\dfrac{1}{(1+s)^2}$$

Applying the inverse Laplace Transform :

> $$F(t)=ate^{-t}$$

as awaited.

---

**Remark** : why is there a difference between ordinary convolution

$$\int_{u=-\infty}^{u=+\infty} F(u) \cos(t - u) du\tag{1}$$

and convolution of causal functions $$\int^t_0 F(u) \cos(t - u) du \ \ ? \ \tag{2}$$

Why are there different bounds in (1) and (2) for the same operation (convolation) ?

As the explanation is not often given, here is one.

Let $H$ denote the Heaviside function, equal to $0$ on $\mathbb{R_-}$ and equal to $1$ on $\mathbb{R_+}$.

Let us "causalize" (!) the functions in the integrand, of (1), i.e., let us take $H(u)F(u)$ instead of $F(u)$ and $H(t-u)\cos(t-u)$ instead of $\cos(t-u).$
As we can write :

$$H(u)H(t-u)=rect_{[0,t]}(u)$$

("characteristic function" of $[0,t]$). This explains why the integrand is $0$ outside $[0,t]$, otherwise said that the new integration interval is $[0,t]$.

Comment: @Lutzl : you are perfectly right. Thanks. Corrected.